# Trying to open a video with Python using os but console says failed to find directory

Tags: python, operating-system

I am using the bellow code to open a video

```
def play_movie(path):
    from os import startfile
    startfile(path)


def start_project():
    play_movie("C:\\Users\\vasco\\Downloads\\Video1")
```

but it gives me an error saying it cant find the file

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/Users/vasco/PycharmProjects/Trabalho_do_Vicente/Projeto.py", line 10, in start_project
    play_movie("C:\\Users\\vasco\\Downloads\\Video1")
  File "C:/Users/vasco/PycharmProjects/Trabalho_do_Vicente/Projeto.py", line 6, in play_movie
    startfile(path)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\vasco\\Downloads\\Video1'
```

can anyone help me?
I used the properties of a file to find its directory and then added its name on front of it, am i doing something wrong?

I tried switching the directory of the video and its name too, but always gives me this message, if i remove the name of the video from the path, it just opens the windows explorer on that location

Comment: Are you sure the video has no file extension like `Video1.avi`, `Video1.mp4`, ... ? It might be better to check the path using [os.path.exists(path)](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) before trying to play the video.

Comment: That was it! Lol im dumb, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There might be 2 mistakes.
The first one is that it may not exist. You can fix this using os.path.isfile().

The Second one might be that you put 2 slashes after every directory, and there is no extension for the video.

The code ideally can be:

```
def play_movie(path):
    import os
    if os.path.isfile(path):
         os.startfile(path)
    else:
         print("Error! The file doesn't exist")


def start_project():
    play_movie("C:\Users\vasco\Downloads\Video1.mp4")
```

or even:

```
def play_movie(path):
    import os
    try:
         os.startfile(path)
    except:
         print("Error! The file doesn't exist")


def start_project():
    play_movie("C:\Users\vasco\Downloads\Video1.mp4")
```